# The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/Image/Uploaded/Panorama.jpg' is not allowed

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-permissions, sql-grant

I've a link button:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" Text="View" PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("Name", "../Image/Uploaded/{0}") %>'>
```

The Eval value is based on what image is loaded to the formview.

For example, I want to view the Panorama.jpg image and while I am clicking that linkbutton, the error shows:

```
The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/Image/Uploaded/Panorama.jpg' is not allowed.
```

I've tried using this code to solved but it is the same:

```
Dim imgUplPath As String = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath & "../Image/Uploaded/"
Dim f2 As New FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, imgUplPath)
Try
    f2.Demand()
Catch s As SecurityException
    Console.WriteLine(s.Message)
End Try
```

Anyone can help me, please? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do a `POST` request to an image resource - `jpg`. That's not valid; there's no handler for `POST` requests for `jpg` resources.

Perhaps what you are looking for is to link right to the image URL, instead of using the `PostBackUrl` of a `LinkButton`

Comment: Thanks a lot :) . I've tried to change the LinkButton become <a href> and it's work.

Answer (score 0):

In your header , you will need to allow POST

Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,OPTIONS")

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that you are trying to use the [`ImageButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.aspx) control as opposed to the `LinkButton` control and you are probably looking for `ImageUrl`  instead of `PostBackUrl`. `ImageUrl` ends up being rendered as `src` on the html `img` element. `PostBackUrl` is the URL that will be used to post back when the image button is clicked.